# Compare element "i" from one np.array with row "i" in a 2D-np.array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Say I have

```py
a = np.array([0,1,2])
b = np.array([[0,1,3,4],[2,1,0,0],[2,1,2,3]])
```

what I want is to compare `a[i]==b[i]` e.g a result being

```py
np.some_function(a,b,axis=0)

#[[0],[1],[0,2]]
# or
#[[True, False, False, False],[False,True,False,False],[True,False,True,False]]
```

I can do it easy with a loop, but I wonder if it could be vectorized?
Note, my `a` and `b` (can be) rather large.

Comment: Use: `a[:,None]==b` / `np.where(a[:,None]==b)`